# Rust output after semaphore release hangs the thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

Consider this code. When you try to `println!("why?");` consumer threads will never end.  Without outputing threads join successfully. You can also print some string before semaphore release, but not after it. Why?

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
    Arc, Condvar, Mutex,
};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

pub struct Semaphore {
    lock: Mutex<isize>,
    cvar: Condvar,
}

impl Semaphore {
    pub fn new(count: isize) -> Semaphore {
        Semaphore {
            lock: Mutex::new(count),
            cvar: Condvar::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn acquire(&self) {
        let mut count = self.lock.lock().unwrap();
        while *count <= 0 {
            count = self.cvar.wait(count).unwrap();
        }
        *count -= 1;
    }

    pub fn release(&self) {
        *self.lock.lock().unwrap() += 1;
        self.cvar.notify_one();
    }
}

fn main() {
    const MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH: isize = 5;
    const PRODUCER_NUMBER: u32 = 10;
    const CONSUMER_NUMBER: u32 = 10;

    let item_queue = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()));
    let queue_length = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(0));
    let empty_number = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH));
    let is_running = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));

    let mut producers = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..PRODUCER_NUMBER {
        producers.push(thread::spawn({
            let item_queue = item_queue.clone();
            let queue_length = queue_length.clone();
            let empty_number = empty_number.clone();
            let is_running = is_running.clone();
            move || producer(item_queue, queue_length, empty_number, is_running)
        }));
    }

    let mut consumers = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..CONSUMER_NUMBER {
        consumers.push(thread::spawn({
            let item_queue = item_queue.clone();
            let queue_length = queue_length.clone();
            let empty_number = empty_number.clone();
            let is_running = is_running.clone();
            move || consumer(item_queue, queue_length, empty_number, is_running)
        }));
    }

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));

    is_running.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);

    for prod in producers {
        let _ = prod.join();
    }

    for cons in consumers {
        let _ = cons.join();
    }
}

struct Item {}

fn producer(
    item_queue: Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<Item>>>,
    queue_length: Arc<Semaphore>,
    empty_number: Arc<Semaphore>,
    is_running: Arc<AtomicBool>,
) {
    while is_running.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        let item = Item {};

        empty_number.acquire();
        {
            let mut item_queue = item_queue.lock().unwrap();
            item_queue.push_back(item);
        }
        queue_length.release();
    }
}

fn consumer(
    item_queue: Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<Item>>>,
    queue_length: Arc<Semaphore>,
    empty_number: Arc<Semaphore>,
    is_running: Arc<AtomicBool>,
) {
    while is_running.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        let item;

        queue_length.acquire();
        {
            let mut item_queue = item_queue.lock().unwrap();
            item = item_queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        }
        empty_number.release();

        println!("why?");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it's related to the fact that `println!` grabs a lock on `stdout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I needed to implement `acquire_timeout` method because `is_running` can become `false` when we are already inside the loop: there will be no available items but we will be waiting for them thus timeout is needed.

Firstly I implemented it wrong and thus replaced with standard `acquire` in my code. But then I wrote it properly and it fixed the problem.
Here's the code of the method:

```
pub fn acquire_timeout(&self, dur: Duration) -> bool {
    let mut count = self.lock.lock().unwrap();
    match self.cvar.wait_timeout(count, dur) {
        Ok((new_count, timeout)) if !timeout.timed_out() => {
                count = new_count;
                if *count > 0 {
                    *count -= 1;
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            },
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

And then I use this:

```
while !queue_length.acquire_timeout(Duration::from_millis(50)) {
    if !is_running.load(Ordering::Relaxed) && queue_length.get_value() == 0 {
        return;
    }
}
```

instead of this:

```
queue_length.acquire();
```

Method `get_value` returns current value of the semaphore.